# 404 on custom contact module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, contact-form

I have created a basic module that extends the contact form, the issue is that when I try to view the form I get a 404, no errors just 404.

What I want to achieve is a trade account form which looks like a register form but it's really the contact form just with more fields.

I have created my module within the /app/code folder and called it **Contact2020/Trade** with the following inside:

**Block** Folder has the file **ContactForm.php** with the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Contact2020\Trade\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Main contact form block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class ContactForm extends Template
{
    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns action url for contact form
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('trade/index/register', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
}
```

Then I have the **Controller/Index** folder with **Register.php** file with the following:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Contact2020\Trade\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Register extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Show Contact Us page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    }
}
```

I then have **etc/frontend** with **routes.xml** with the following:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="trade" frontName="trade">
            <module name="Contact2020_Trade" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I have got **view/frontend/layout** with **trade_index_register.xml** which has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Trade Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Contact2020\Trade\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Contact2020_Trade::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And lastly I have **/view/frontend/templates** with **form.phtml** which just has my html form:

```
<form class="form tradeform"
      action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
      id="trade-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="field companyname required">
            <label class="label" for="companyname"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Company Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="companyname" id="companyname" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Company Name')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('companyname') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field companynumber required">
            <label class="label" for="companynumber"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Company Ltd Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="companynumber" id="companynumber" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Company Ltd Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('companynumber') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field tradingaddress required">
            <label class="label" for="tradingaddress"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Company Trading Address')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="tradingaddress" id="tradingaddress" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Company Trading Address')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('tradingaddress') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field companycontactnumber required">
            <label class="label" for="companycontactnumber"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Company Contact Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="companycontactnumber" id="companycontactnumber" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Company Contact Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('companycontactnumber') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field companyemail required">
            <label class="label" for="companyemail"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Company Contact Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="companyemail" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Company Contact Email')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('companyemail') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field fullname required">
            <label class="label" for="fullname"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Full Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="fullname" id="fullname" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Full Name')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('fullname') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field birthday required">
            <label class="label" for="birthday"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('DD')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="birthday" id="birthday" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('DD')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('birthday') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field birthmonth required">
            <label class="label" for="birthmonth"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('MM')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="birthmonth" id="birthmonth" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('MM')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('birthmonth') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field birthyear required">
            <label class="label" for="birthyear"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('YYYY')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="birthyear" id="birthyear" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('YYYY')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('birthyear') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field address required">
            <label class="label" for="address"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="address" id="address" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Address')) ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="5" data-validate="{required:true}"><?= $block->escapeHtml($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('address')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field address2 required">
            <label class="label" for="address2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address (If not lived at current address for 3 years or more)')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="address2" id="address2" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Address (If not lived at current address for 3 years or more)')) ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="5" data-validate="{required:true}"><?= $block->escapeHtml($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('address2')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field contacttelephone">
            <label class="label" for="contacttelephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="contacttelephone" id="contacttelephone" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Contact Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('contacttelephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field contactemail required">
            <label class="label" for="contactemail"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="contactemail" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Contact Email')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('contactemail') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field tradingname required">
            <label class="label" for="tradingname"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Trading Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="tradingname" id="tradingname" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Trading Name')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('tradingname') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If I navigate to http://localhost:8888/store/trade/index/register I get a 404, but If I navigate to http://localhost:8888/store/contact/index/index I can see the default contact form. I have run these commands in my console:

- php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento setup:upgrade php -d
- memory_limit=2048M bin/magento setup:di:compile php -d
- memory_limit=2048M bin/magento cache:flush

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I understand, your real bottleneck is to render the form as a landing page.

I have taken your files and updated them only slightly. I would like to give you the module that works at my end; this way, you would be able to install it and have it running on your local..
--> If you want this, I will give you a chat url for us to exchange this plugin as I have some issues with bitbucket and cannot push my module at the moment.

Once your have the module, you may uninstall your (temporarily) and install mine.
then once setup:upgrade is run, you may go to

`<magento_url>/trade` and you will see your form

Also, if you submit the form, it will call the second url `<magento_url>/trade/index/register`

It may not be exactly where you wanted to go but I hope this module will give you a controller working. Then, you may see what was breaking yours and eventually you will be able to use your module again.

Do let me know when I can put the file on a chat place.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response, I've now included the contents of my form.php file

Comment: did you resolve it? happy to dig further with you

Comment: No, still not resolved